# flatMap on elements of a set

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, flatmap

I have a `Map<String, Set<String>>`, let's say it is
`{"a": {"a1", "a2", "a3"}, "b": {"b1", "b2", "b3"}, "c": {"c1", "c2"}, "d": {}}`

I have a stream of sets of map keys, and I want to flatmap each element of the streamed set to the elements of the corresponding value set in my map, e.g.

INPUT STREAM:

```
{"a","b"}
{"a","c"}
{"b","c","d"}
```

OUTPUT STREAM:

```
//first set
{"a1","b1"}
{"a1","b2"}
{"a1","b3"}
{"a2","b1"}
{"a2","b2"}
{"a2","b3"}
{"a3","b1"}
{"a3","b2"}
{"a3","b3"}
//second set
{"a1","c1"}
{"a1","c2"}
{"a2","c1"}
{"a2","c2"}
{"a3","c1"}
{"a3","c2"}
//third set would be flatmapped to nothing, as "d" is mapped to an empty set
```

How can I do this using Java8 streams?

Is there a better way to do it using only the Java SE 8 API?

Comment: No. You want all *combinations*. Streams work with elements, one at a time. You can’t combine elements from elsewhere in the stream.

Comment: Yes correct as said by @Bohemian Streams works with elements at a time and u want all combinations of it so u can't use streams

Comment: A better way than what? What does your attempt look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Apache Commons Collections

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

An exsample:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // With an ArrayList for the values
        MultiValuedMap<String, String> map1 = new ArrayListValuedHashMap<>();
        map1.put("a", "a1");
        map1.put("a", "a2");
        map1.put("a", "a3");
        map1.put("a", "a4");
        map1.put("a", "a5");
        map1.put("b", "b1");
        map1.put("b", "b1");
        map1.put("b", "b3");
        map1.put("b", "b4");
        map1.put("b", "b5");
        map1.entries().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue()));
        System.out.println("----");
        // With a HashSet for the values
        MultiValuedMap<String, String> map2 = new HashSetValuedHashMap<>(map1);
        map2.entries().forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " - " + e.getValue()));
    }
}
```

The output look like this:

```
a - a1
a - a2
a - a3
a - a4
a - a5
b - b1
b - b1
b - b3
b - b4
b - b5
----
a - a1
a - a2
a - a3
a - a4
a - a5
b - b3
b - b4
b - b5
b - b1
```